# How to change value of html header

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using `redirect` to pass the current user's username to some other page, as so...

```
var current_user = encodeURIComponent(req.body.log_username);
res.redirect('/home?valid=' + current_user);
```

...The receiving page has the following code...

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
    var passedVariable = req.query.valid;
    console.log(passedVariable);
});
```

The correct username is passed through, but I need to know how I can incorporate the username into my html.

For example, when the html is rendered, I want the header to say `"Welcome 'username'"`

How can I do this? With php this is relatively simple, but I am at a loss with node js.

Comment: Why not use actual server-side sessions and store user information that way? Persisting (session) data like the way you are suggesting *could be* dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will send a post request to login and after successful login, you will be redirected to `/` route. Here you have `username` in `passedVariable` variable in your code. You can pass this variable to main page where you can render it in your header.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   var passedVariable = req.query.valid;
   console.log(passedVariable);
   res.render('home', { title: 'Express', username: passedVariable });
});
```

Now you will get this variable in your main page template and you can use it. For `ejs`, code will look like

```
<p><%= username %></p>
```

For `jade`

```
p= username
```

Templates side code depends on your choice of technology, whether you are using `ejs` or `jade`